# Excel Checkboxes move on each spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel, debugging, checkbox

I was having a problem with the "bug" that moves checkboxes around

to solve this I wrote a quick little vba code to keep them in line

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

```
With Sheet3.Shapes("Group 5")
    .Top = Range("B6").Top + Range("B6").Height / 2 - .Height / 2
    .Left = Range("B6").Left + Range("B6").Left / 2
End With
```

End Sub

This works fine but if below the Group 5 I add a shape from sheet 4, They will move when I don't want them to.

So if I save on sheet 3, all of sheet 3's will move to the correct location (Which is good). Then if I click over to sheet 4, they are shifted a tad bit and visa versa. Does anyone know why this would be happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using With, adjust that with this:

```
With Sheet3
    .Shapes("Group 5").Top = .Range("B6").Top + Range("B6").Height / 2 - .Height / 2
    .Shapes("Group 5").Left = .Range("B6").Left + Range("B6").Left / 2
End With
```

I think that should work, if not, just add "Sheet3." before the two Range("B6") lines.  THis would make it explicit that the range used is that sheet.  I think what's happening is when you switch sheets, that range changes to the B6 on the new sheet you activated.

edit: Also, I assume "Sheet3" is a worksheet variable? Otherwise, you need Sheets("Sheet3")

Comment: It throws me some errors at the moment my current code is     With Sheets("Sheet3")
        .Shapes("Group 5").Top = Sheet3.Range("B6").Top + Sheet3.Range("B6").Height / 2 - .Height / 2
        .Shapes("Group 5").Left = Sheet3.Range("B6").Left + Sheet3.Range("B6").Left / 2
    End With

Answer (score 0):

I hope I am understanding your issue correctly. If you want a shape to stay in the same spot relative to the worksheet borders not matter what happens in worksheet, you can set the `Object Positioning` option to `Don't move or size with cells.` You do this by right-clicking on the shape, click `Format Control` then select the `Properties` tab, and you will see the option there. Then you shouldn't need VBA code to adjust it.